# Eclipse error with archived java projects "editor does not contain main type"

Tags: java, eclipse

I am receiving the errors: *Editor does not contain main type*, or, *Selection does not contain main type* when I import an archived Java project into Eclipse and try to run it. I have gotten this error on several different operating systems.

**Archive Protocol**

- Export project
- General->Archive File
- All are selected: project folder, .classpath and .project

  - [x] save in zip format
  - [x] create directory structure for files
  - [x] compress contents of file

**A Work Around That May Explain It...** *but how?!*

I notice that when I import an archived project into an existing project (a blank Java project), The folder hierarchy is something like:

- Project

  - src
  - bin
  - imported_project

    - bin
    - src

      - actual_code.java

Now, when I try to run `actual_code.java`, I get the above error. I discovered the following work around: if I drag `actual_code.java` and drop it into **Project->src** *and then* run it, it works.

This is a nice work around. However, I would prefer to be able to run the imported project without moving things around. **Any suggestions on how to do this?** It seems like it *should be* a trivial fix--it simply seems like the project isn't importing to where it ought to.

**And yes...**

I have tried every method I have come across to remedy this. That includes quite a few from this site and others: syntax, libraries, source path, restart eclipse, rearchive, different operating systems, different machines... etc.

The `.java` files are in the `src` folder before I archive them, and my build path *seems* correct.

Answer (score 1):

You could import the archive as a Project instead of as files into a newly created blank project. Use Import > Existing Projects into Workspace. Then, use Select archive file.

Comment: +1 This is a nice work around. More straight forward than the one I discovered...! I would still like to understand why importing the archive into an existing project generates this error.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to put the src folder of your imported_project in classpath.

Right click on your project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source -> Add Folder

[image]

Comment: When I click **Add Folder**, I have the expected Project_Name->drop down menu (.settings, bin, src). The `src` folder is shaded blue (not clickable). I think this indicates it is already included, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same error ajnd after reading above article i just drag/drop my class-file to src and new class-file generated in src is working fine .

Comment: It is a Question and Answer site. You are supposed to answer, not to comment here. Check out [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem after I New/Java Project then pulling src, docs, lib, examples, ... folders. I could not import it as an Eclipse project since the code is not an Eclipse project. The main is right there in the example code, but the IDE would find it.

The solution for me is deleting the project from the IDE, then recreating it with the Eclipse IDE. When recreating, the IDE cached all the sub-folders for me. Also, make sure you add the code onto the Java Build Path as Source using the 'Configure Build Path...' of the project.

Restarting IDE, closing then reopening the file didn't help me.